# CSS3 transition: Background working, text not changing color?

Tags: css

I have created a `div` that slides the background down to reveal a bio picture. It uses a 100px wide x 200px tall background, with the bottom square grey and the top square the picture. When you hover over it moves the background down to show the bio photo.

```
#bio-1 {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(../images/kermit.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
-webkit-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;  
-moz-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;  
-o-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out;  
transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out; }
```

and then the hover option:

```
#bio-1:hover {
background-position: top; }
```

But when I try to change the text color, it keeps reverting back to the standard grey I have set on the paragraph it sits within? So this is within `.content` which is within `.wrap` ...but I want to get this to work too:

```
#bio-1 {
display: block;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: #333;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(../images/kermit.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: bottom;
-webkit-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;  
-moz-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;  
-o-transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out;  
transition:background-position 0.3s ease-in-out, color 0.3s ease-in-out; }

#bio-1:hover {
background-position: top;
color: #fff; }
```

but it seems to be ignoring the text color? I have even tried the !important tag ...it still only shows the text as grey?

How can I get this to change the text color too? It just doesn't seem to want to listen to this particular change. I have tried this in IE, FF & CHROME.

Answer (score 1):

Try This will work fine **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/qcW8F/)**

```
#bio-1 {
   display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(../images/kermit.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-position .3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-position .3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    -o-transition: background-position .3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
    transition: background-position .3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;
}
```

Comment: +1 But it is advisable that your keep in your answer only the stuff you've changed to make things work, not just copy the entire class